# Android to iOS AirDrop?

Tags: android, ios, airdrop

Out of curiosity... has anyone ever been able to integrate AirDrop functionality into an Android app?

I really don't care about receiving any information on the Android side, but am hoping I can send information to the iOS side from Android. I'm hoping to find someone with a more in-depth understanding of how it works and if it is physically possible. Also, any direction on whether Apple has proprietary use over the protocol (or if it is just the name and branding) would be awesome!

Trying to build a cross-platform app and getting pretty close, but this would just extremely convenient if it works out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible as AirDrop uses Bluetooth to create a peer-to-peer Wi-Fi network between the devices. Each device creates a firewall around the connection and files are sent encrypted, which actually makes it safer than transferring via email. AirDrop will automatically detect nearby supported devices, and the devices only need to be close enough to establish a good Wi-Fi connection, making it possible to share files across several rooms.

Some Android devices use a combination of Near Field Communications (NFC) and Bluetooth to share files. But both Bluetooth and NFC are relatively slow compared Wi-Fi, which makes sharing larger files using AirDrop much faster and more convenient.

Regarding protocol, I don't think Apple has made it public and as far as I know Apple they must have patented it. Since AirDrop uses Bluetooth as well, and Android and iPhone Bluetooth are not compatible. Hence, due to all these reasons, we did not see any Android app that can send data via AirDrop.

Comment: FYI a lot of Android file sharing solutions also use wifi, for example, it could use a hotspot, WiFi direct, or the same router they connected to transmit data, this is not an AirDrop only thing.